# Deploy bookinfo into another namespace, access ingress gateway return 404. How to configure virtualservice for non-default namespace?

Tags: istio

I am using ***istio 1.0.2 version*** with security feature (istio-demo-auth.yaml) and k8s  version is v1.9.1.

- Follow the istio.io example for bookinfo. Successful.

  ```
  curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://ingressip:port/productpage
  return 200
  ```
- Delete the bookinfo application, then change the yaml file, make all the app in the (multitenancy) namespace.

  a. deploy the bookinfo into multitenancy namespace:

  ```
  kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo-multitenancy.yaml)
  ```

  b. define the ingress gateway for the application for multitenancy:

  ```
  kubectl apply -f samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway-multitenancy.yaml

          apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
          kind: VirtualService
          metadata:
            name: bookinfo
            namespace: multitenancy
          spec:
            hosts:
            - "*"
            gateways:
            - bookinfo-gateway
            http:
            - match:
              - uri:
                  exact: /productpage
              - uri:
                  exact: /login
              - uri:
                  exact: /logout
              - uri:
                  prefix: /api/v1/products
              route:
              - destination:
                  host: productpage
                  port:
                    number: 9080
  ```

  c. confirm the app is running:

  ```
  curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://ingressip:port/productpage 

  Return 404
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify in the destination's host: `productpage.multitenancy.svc.cluster.local`. Since the gateway is in the `default` namespace (I assume you use the `bookinfo-gateway` `Gateway` definition from the standard bookinfo), put the `VirtualService` in the `default` namespace as well.

Comment: Thanks Vadim Eisenberg, it works after I did what you told. I have another question, is that the Gateway and VirtualService must in the same namespace.

Comment: @N.SK, I think the answer is yes, the Gateway and VirtualService must in the same namespace.

Comment: @N.SK if the answer provided is a solution to your issue, please consider accepting it as best answer.